# EchoBot: How does control flow from BotController to EchoBot

Tags: botframework

I am looking at the EchoBot sample and trying to understand it. I see that BotController is mapped to api/messages and HttpPost which in turn invokes Adapter.ProcessAsync. But how does this translate into EchoBot.OnMessageActivityAsync call? I tried to set up a breakpoint and see the call stack but that doesn't help ( see attached screenshot).

[image]

I understand BotFrameworkHttpAdapter is invoked via dependency injection. But I don't know how we end up in EchoBot eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the answer to this you really have to dive into the source code, so I hope you've got your scuba diving gear because we're going deep.

**Step 1**

Inside the `BotController.cs` [file](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/907b983bab22a6226fe896b76b79cdb40b604fb8/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/Controllers/BotController.cs#L32) the following piece of code is called:

```
await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);
```

which calls the `ProcessAsync` method on the `IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter` interface.

**Step 2**

Inside the `Startup.cs` [file](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/907b983bab22a6226fe896b76b79cdb40b604fb8/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/Startup.cs#L36) we have the following line:

```
services.AddSingleton<IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter, BotFrameworkHttpAdapter>();
```

which says that every time we ask for an `IBotFrameworkHttpAdapter`, provide the same instance of `BotFrameworkHttpAdapter` - essentially a static variable, you can read more about dependency injection service lifetimes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes).

**Step 3**

Inside the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` package we have the [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/d9dc6f6a20ec08207ee8182c613edff11ce295b5/libraries/integration/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core/BotFrameworkHttpAdapter.cs#L45) for the `ProcessAsync` method, that can for our purposes be reduced to the following line:

```
var invokeResponse = await ProcessActivityAsync(authHeader, activity, bot.OnTurnAsync, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

which calls `ProcessActivityAsync` which is another function that lives in this library - the important part here is the `bot.OnTurnAsync` parameter being passed in.

**Step 5**

Also inside the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` package is the [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/eb16f257169987ff680dfc5297b572be41635d6f/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotFrameworkAdapter.cs#L241) for `ProcessActivityAsync`:

```
return await ProcessActivityAsync(claimsIdentity, activity, callback, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

which calls an overload of the same method, but before we move on from here, the `callback` parameter is the `bot.OnTurnAsync` parameter that was passed through before.

**Step 6**

The overload of `ProcessActivityAsync` is also [implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/eb16f257169987ff680dfc5297b572be41635d6f/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotFrameworkAdapter.cs#L258) inside the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` package, and can be simplified to this line:

```
await RunPipelineAsync(context, callback, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

where `callback` is `bot.OnTurnAsync`.

**Step 7**

Digging deeper still we find the [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/c66148b11a28ad6af99cefb304384410b3768e4b/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotAdapter.cs#L158) of the `RunPipelineAsync` method inside of the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` package which is were things start to get a bit fuzzy... Theoretically we want to fall through to the `else` block where the `callback` (i.e. `bot.OnTurnAsync`) is called:

```
// Call any registered Middleware Components looking for ReceiveActivityAsync()
if (turnContext.Activity != null)
{
    // Other code  
}
else
{
    // call back to caller on proactive case
    if (callback != null)
    {
        await callback(turnContext, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

However, back in Step 6 we also had [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/eb16f257169987ff680dfc5297b572be41635d6f/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotFrameworkAdapter.cs#L264) line:

```
using (var context = new TurnContext(this, activity))
```

where the context is created, and the activity property is [initialised](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/fb65b0063c0e8df711c92247ba156d1e088012c4/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/TurnContext.cs#L36). This same `context` is pass through to the `RunPipelineAsync` call, which means that we *will not fall through to the else block...*

But there are the following comment on the `RunPipelineAsync` method:

```
/// <param name="callback">A callback method to run at the end of the pipeline.</param>
```

and inside the `remarks` section:

```
...Once control reaches the end of the pipeline, the adapter calls
the <paramref name="callback"/> method...
```

So I believe is it safe to say that our `callback` method is being executed which means that we continue by bubbling back up the chain to resolve the function that `callback` maps to (`bot.OnTurnAsync`).

**Step 8**

In `BotController` we pass in an instance of `IBot` to the `ProcessAsync` method, and in `Startup` we wire up all requests for an `IBot` to return an instance of `EchoBot` like so:

```
// Create the bot as a transient. In this case the ASP Controller is expecting an IBot.
services.AddTransient<IBot, EchoBot>();
```

The `EchoBot` [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/907b983bab22a6226fe896b76b79cdb40b604fb8/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/Bots/EchoBot.cs#L12) inherits from the `ActivityHandler` class:

```
public class EchoBot : ActivityHandler
```

**Step 9**

The `ActivityHandler` class provides a default [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/be7376490a58f6139b3d7a5980ce1c94653403a7/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ActivityHandler.cs#L29) for the `OnTurnAsync` method which I will simplify to:

```
switch (turnContext.Activity.Type)
{
   case ActivityTypes.Message:
       return OnMessageActivityAsync(new DelegatingTurnContext<IMessageActivity>(turnContext), cancellationToken);
   // Other cases
}
```

which the `OnMessageActivityAsync` method on the same class that has an [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/be7376490a58f6139b3d7a5980ce1c94653403a7/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ActivityHandler.cs#L72) that returns a completed task, i.e. is a no-op, however it is a virtual method - classes which inherit `ActivityHandler` can provide their own implementation.

**Step 10**

A custom [implementation](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/907b983bab22a6226fe896b76b79cdb40b604fb8/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/Bots/EchoBot.cs#L14) for `OnMessageActivityAsync` is provided inside the `EchoBot` class:

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Echo: {turnContext.Activity.Text}"), cancellationToken);
}
```

where the user's input is echoed back to them, and thus our journey ends.

---

Regarding Step 7, the Microsoft team are pretty active on SO for things tagged with `botframework` so it might be best to get @mdrichardson or @tdurnford to clarify what happens here.

---

As an aside in Visual Studio you can debug some library code by enabling the following option:

- Tools --> Options --> Debugger
- Uncheck "Enable Just my Code"

Also if you enable navigation to decompiled sources (you will have to accept a legal notification popup) by doing [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2019#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c):

- Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> C# --> Advanced
- Check "Enable navigation to decompiled sources"

You will be able to inspect the source code of external packages within Visual Studio itself.

Comment: Stannet Know this that you are awesome and very kind. Your answer is very complete and very helpful. I am very grateful.